# How to use Javascript "export" and "import" functions properly?

Tags: javascript, function, import, export

I want to export function from lib.js file to main.js file.
I have

```
// lib.js
export const sqrt = Math.sqrt;
export function square(x) {
   return x * x;
}
export function diag(x, y) {
   return sqrt(square(x) + square(y));
}

// main.js 



import { square, diag } from 'lib';
console.log(square(11)); // 121
console.log(diag(4, 3)); // 5
```

After I connected main.js file to index.html file, in console I can find:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export  lib.js:1
```

What am I doing wrong? Or how to use "export" and "import" properly?

Comment: check those links: [link1](https://egghead.io/lessons/ecmascript-6-es6-modules-es2015-import-and-export) , [link2](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/import)
PD: Are you using ES6?

Comment: `import` and `export` are not fully supported in the browser.  You usually need a *bundler* (like Webpack) in order to create a package that has everything in it for the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is finally solved after weeks. I'd never before used node.js enviroment and I had an interview task where functions should look like this:

```
    exports.functionName = () => {
       // smth here
    };
```

And that is why I've tried to use import, cause I thought it was misspelling in description of the task. 
But the solution was to install node globally. Create .js file with that function above, and just run in like this in terminal:

```
cd TaskDirectory
node nameOfFile.js
```

For all those newbies, like me. You can all your console.log's inside terminal, so you don't have to stick your .js file to .html to debug and check log's in browser.

Answer (score 1):

The native import is still not supported in node v6 and some browsers.

[Import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

You can use Typescript for import statement support in browsers

Answer (score 0):

You may refer mozilla documentation -

[1) export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)

[2) import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)