# Export class as a module in webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, es6-class

I'm using Webpack to import a javascript file that has a single class.

**my_class.js**

```
console.log('hello from my_class');

class myClass {
    // ...
}
```

**index.js**

```
import './my_class.js';
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use this class on a page.

**index.html**

```
<script src="./dist/bundle.js"></script>
<script>
    
    const myClass = new myClass();

</script>
```

I am able to seem my console log ("hello from my_class") but `myClass` is showing up as undefined.

`Uncaught ReferenceError: myClass is not defined`

What do I need to do such that `myClass` is exported and available in the markup?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Javascript "export" and "import" functions properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44624678/how-to-use-javascript-export-and-import-functions-properly)

Comment: Not really. I tried using `exports.myClass = myClass` at the bottom of `my_class.js` but `myClass` was still undefined on the front end. Im thinking its because `exports` is in the node environment and Im trying to use it on front end, but I though webpack would take care of all that?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you should export the class.

```
export class myClass {
    // ...
}
```

And for browsers you should use IIFE or UMD format:

```
output: {
  library: 'someLibName',
  libraryTarget: 'umd',
  filename: 'bundle.js'
}
```

2021 and webpack thinks federated apps are higher priority than adding ES module support ‍♂️ Use rollup if you don't want to use UMD.

And reference: `someLibName.myClass`

Comment: no dice : / after adding export statement, additional directives in output, and referencing as property of `someLibName`, Im still getting the same undefined error

Answer (score 0):

As you have not exported class from `my_class.js` file, you will not be able to import it.

```
console.log('hello from my_class');

class myClass {
    // ...
}

export default myClass;
```

And your import should be like

```
import myClass from './my_class.js';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just register your class on the window object when the module executes. In the index.js file, simply add code like this:

```
if (!window.myClass) {
    window.myClass = new myClass();
}
```

That way around, there is no need for extra configuration of webpack.