# Can't use JS class with symfony 6 webpack encore

Tags: javascript, webpack-encore, symfony6

I'm building a "symfony bundle" that takes care of autocompletion in my project. The bundle consists in a js class that does the job of listening for user inputs, sends them via Ajx to a php scirpt (currently, i will then create a controller in the bundle and relevant models, etc. for that later).
When I run

```
yarn encore dev,
```

everything goes fine the AutoCompleteJs file is avalaible, but I get this error "AutoComplete is not defined". If I replace the code created for me in the public directory by the code I created in the first place, then the AutoComplete class works fine and it does its job : giving me suggestions when I type one or more letter in the input. But If I run

```
yarn encore dev,
```

then it breaks everything.
I'm sorry if I don't use the right terms like compile, ect. I'm very new to Webpack Encore (or webpack...).
If it helps, this how I call the class from my template :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
   const ac = new AutoComplete();
});
```

Can somoeone explain me what I'm doing wrong please? My code is very simple and works like a charm when I use it in a "normal web page".
Thanks for any help or advice you will provide me with.

Edited for typos and changed title for precision.
M.

Comment: Most likely the file where the AutoComplete class is defined is not being imported into the template being rendered. The typical pattern is to import all your assets (js and css) into your app.js file (or main.js, or whatever you've called your entry point file) and then add a link to that file in your base template. I recommend checking out the [Encore docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html#configuring-encore-webpack) and read through the parts on entry points and importing modules.

Comment: Hi, and thank you. The code of the class appears in the final build directory. But the class, or its constructor is first rendered as function,: 
`var AutoComplete = /*#__PURE__*/function () {
  function AutoComplete() {...`
Then there is this : 
`createClass(AutoComplete, [{...`  
I've followed the doc you gave me in the first place and that's where I'm headed.
I also tried to reference my class in app.js (i always keep defaults name when they are good) and no luck. I see my code in the compiled module, but can't use it.

Comment: As I said, if I replace the code generated by webpack-encore with the original code of my class, it works. Meaning that my files are available and I followed the directives you pointed me too. I've seen since yesterday that I wasn't alone in that case but just like, the posts I've read have no solution. So my question is a duplicate I'm affraid See this for an example with code : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66253122/export-class-as-a-module-in-webpack]

Comment: Ok, I think you're right. What i did was referencing my css and my js files with their own entry points in webpack-config.js, but for some reason, this doesn't work. I've added the call for the class and imported the css and js directly from app.js and it now works. So I guess you were right. I can't mark your comment as good answer but to me, it is. So thank you so much @AdamRichard !